# ¿Como hacer para que en CMD se lea el nombre de un archivo y se cree un comando variable con ese nombre?

Tags: cmd, powershell

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente caso.
Diariamente tengo que copiar unos backups en un archivo winrar para reducir su peso, cree un script que revisa carpeta por carpeta previamente configurada, toma el nombre de archivo según el día/mes/año.bak y lo comprime en un archivo que tiene como nombre día/mes/año.rar .
El problema, el día/mes/año se toman de la fecha actual en la que se esta ejecutando el script dejando backups del día anterior o otras fechas afuera teniendo que comprimirlos cada uno manual mente.

Envio un ejemplo de mi actual script, quizas a mas de uno le puede servir.

```
@echo off
  rem 0,2 for mm/dd/yyyy  or 3,2 for dd/mm/yyyy
set month-num=%date:~3,2%
if %month-num%==01 set mo-name=ENERO
if %month-num%==02 set mo-name=FEBRERO
if %month-num%==03 set mo-name=MARZO
if %month-num%==04 set mo-name=ABRIL
if %month-num%==05 set mo-name=MAYO
if %month-num%==06 set mo-name=JUNIO
if %month-num%==07 set mo-name=JULIO
if %month-num%==08 set mo-name=AGOSTO
if %month-num%==09 set mo-name=SEPTIEMBRE
if %month-num%==10 set mo-name=OCTUBRE
if %month-num%==11 set mo-name=NOVIEMBRE
if %month-num%==12 set mo-name=DICIEMBRE

::echo Mes %mo-name%
::echo Mes %month-num%
::echo Dia %date:~0,2%
::echo Ano %date:~6%
::echo El dia es %date:~0,2% , el mes es %mo-name% %month-num% y el ano es %date:~6%

echo ***************************************************************************
echo Registro %date:~6% %mo-name% %date:~0,2%
echo ***************************************************************************

echo **********************
echo Copiando BD_Web

"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" mf -ep1 -idc -y "C:\Backup\BD_Web\BD_Web_%mo-name%%date:~6%.rar" "C:\Backup\BD_Web\BD_Web_backup_%date:~6%_%month-num%*.bak"
```

¿Existe alguna forma de que se pueda tomar el nombre del archivo, leerlo y que el comando final sea con el nombre del archivo?

Quedo atento a sus comentarios